# How to make abs() , sqrt() (from sympy) compare with value?

Tags: python, math

I am try to check the intervals over which the function is increasing and the intervals where it is decreasing *(The intervals only check in (-oo;0) or (0;+oo) or Real number)*. Of course my code only serve in simple function such as: 
***(x^(-5))*** ; ***(x^3 + x)*** ; ***(x^4 + 3*(x^2) *- 1)***

The problem here I must input all this function: ***(sqrt(abs(x)))*** ; ***(1/(abs(x)))***

When I input all that, I realize when the code run to compare calculation --> It cannot compare and It's error

*Example:*
 - Input: ***(sympy.sqrt(sympy.abs(x)))***
*(I comment in my code where the error take from)*
 - Ouput: ***Error***

```
import sympy
import math
import inspect
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def check_inc_des(f, x_min=-100, x_max=100, n_sample=100):
  x = sympy.symbols('x')
  expr = f(x)
  limit_expr = sympy.limit(expr, x, 0)
  if limit_expr == -math.inf or limit_expr == math.inf:
    for k in np.linspace(x_min, -0.5, n_sample):
        a = sympy.diff(f(x))
        a = a.subs(sympy.Symbol("x"), k)
        if a < 0:
          b = "The function is decreasing in the interval (-oo;0)"
          break 
        if a > 0:
          b = "The function is increasing in the interval (-oo;0)"
          break
    for k in np.linspace(0.5, x_max, n_sample):
        a = sympy.diff(f(x))
        a = a.subs(sympy.Symbol("x"), k)
        if a > 0:
          d = "The function is increasing in the interval (0;+oo)"
          break
        if a < 0:
          d = "The function is decreasing in the interval (0;+oo)"
          break
    return b + "\n" +" "+ d
  else:
    for k in np.linspace(x_min, -0.5, n_sample):
        a = sympy.diff(f(x))
        a = a.subs(sympy.Symbol("x"), k)
        if a < 0: #<--------------------------------------------------The error take from here
          b = "The function is decreasing in the interval (-oo;0)"
          break 
        if a > 0:
          b = "The function is increasing in the interval (-oo;0)"
          break
    for k in np.linspace(0.5, x_max, n_sample):
        h = sympy.diff(f(x))
        h = h.subs(sympy.Symbol("x"), k)
        if h > 0:
          d = "The function is increasing in the interval (0;+oo)"
          break
        if h < 0:
          d = "The function is decreasing in the interval (0;+oo)"
          break
    if a < 0 and h < 0:
      return "The function is decreasing in the Real number"
    if a > 0 and h > 0:
      return "The function is increasing in the Real number"
    return b + "\n"+" "+ d

def do_ex_3(fa):
    func_lst = [fa]
    for func in func_lst:
        print(check_inc_des(func))
    return

def f_3x_a(x):
    return x**(-5) #<------------------------------------------------------Where I input

do_ex_3(f_3x_a)
```

*My code upper take example for x^(-5):*
 - Input: ***(x^(-5))***
 - Ouput: ***The function is decreasing in the interval (-oo;0)

 The function is decreasing in the interval (0;+oo)*** 
 Thanks for support!

Comment: You should never try to attempt to compare floating point numbers for equality.  You need to have an epsilon value that designates "close enough", then check `if abs(a) < epsilon: # values are equal`.

Comment: Please be sure to include a question mark within your question itself, not just the title.